# Prevent regex from becoming greedy when using optional tokens?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regex to extract information from different strings.

For example, I have the following JSON:

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "test", // comment
"cost": "$10",
}
```

and want to write a regex that extracts into capture groups (1) the text up to the colon, (2) the text up to the comma, (3) the comma if exists, and (4) the text after the comma.

Starting with the comma being non-optional, I came up with `(.*?): (.*?)(,)(.*?)\n`.

This works correctly. However, I now tried to modify it so the comma is optional, by adding `?`: `(.*?): (.*?)(,?)(.*?)\n`. This breaks down, with what should normally be in capture groups 2 and 3 shifting to group 4.

How can I modify my regex to prevent this from occurring? I would like the modified version to function the same as the original non-optional version when a comma does exist, and when a comma does not exist, shift all text after the colon to group 2.

Comment: If you want to parse JSON, then just call `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! However, I'm trying to make this work for the more general case, with any string and any token I want to be "optional"

Comment: If the comma is optional, what will separate the part before from the part after? How do you determine where the second group stops and the last group starts?

Comment: @trincot That is true, I believe that in the absence of a comma it would make most sense for all text after the colon to be captured in group 2.

Comment: In that case make the second group like `([^,\n\r]*)` -- that way it will greedily capture anything that is not a comma or a line break.

Comment: @trincot Thank you, that works very well. If I understand correctly, in the general case, I would replace `(.*?)(XXX?)` with `([^XXX\n\r]*)(XXX?)` (where XXX is any string).

Comment: No, that will not work, ... it only works when `X` is one character. For multiple characters, you'll need to use negative lookahead.

Comment: @trincot Ah, thanks. If you don't mind, could you provide an implementation of that? I'm very much a beginner to regex, and can't seem to come up with something that's working, haha

Comment: `((?:(?!XXX)[^\r\n])*)((?:XXX)?)`

Comment: @trincot Ah, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the second group capture anything that is not a comma nor a line break:

`(.*?): ([^,\n\r]*)(,?)(.*?)\n`

Note that your regex *requires* the line to end with `\n`. This may be too strict, as the last line of a text might not terminate with `\n`. And there are also texts that use `\r` or `\r\n` as line break. You might want to use the `$` anchor, which also does not actually capture the line break, but just requires it. Use with the `m` (multiline) modifier.